# How can I get the index of smallest value in Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

My DataFrame contains 4 columns: City, District, Area and Price, where Area is float64 and Price is int64.

```
price_min = df['Price'].min()
# area_min = df['Area'].iloc[np.nanargmin(df['Price'])]
# city_min = df['City'].iloc[np.nanargmin(df['Price'])]
area_min = df['Area'].iloc[df['Price'].idxmin()]
city_min = df['City'].iloc[df['Price'].idxmin()]
print(
    f"If you are looking for a cheap accommodation, "
    f"a {area_min} m² apartment for {price_min} PLN is available in {city_min}"

)
```

The commented lines actually work.
But the lines below cause error:

```
result = values.argmin(axis)
TypeError: argmin() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Post the full error traceback.  You shouldn't use `.iloc` when passing index, use `.loc`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), because [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is for selecting by positions, not by labels:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'City':list('abcdef'),
         'District':list('GHIJKL'),
         'Area':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'Price':[271,34,55,74,10,120],

})
print (df)

  City District  Area  Price
0    a        G     7    271
1    b        H     8     34
2    c        I     9     55
3    d        J     4     74
4    e        K     2     10
5    f        L     3    120


#for default index values
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

price_min = df['Price'].min()
area_min = df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin(), 'Area']
city_min = df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin(), 'City']
    
print(
    f"If you are looking for a cheap accommodation, "
    f"a {area_min} m² apartment for {price_min} PLN is available in {city_min}"

)
If you are looking for a cheap accommodation, a 2 m² apartment for 10 PLN is available in e
```

Comment: @FilipSzczybura - What is your pandas version?

Comment: My current version is 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
area_min = df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin()][['Area']]
city_min = df.loc[df['Price'].idxmin()][['City']]
```

Comment: Issue is that `.iloc` is not meant to select by index value, it's for selecting using the position. As mentioned by @jezrael in his answer.

Comment: Same error. I solved it using df['Price'].values.argmin(), but I think it is an easier way to solve it

Comment: @FilipSzczybura Because `.argmin` gives the position of min value while `.idxmin()` gives the index corresponding to minimum value. We are supposed to pass position to the `.iloc` hence `.argmin` works fine but `.idxmin` doesn't.

Comment: but why do i need .values attribute? I think it should work fine with a single argmin/idxmin

Comment: AFAIK`.argmin` is not there in pandas series, it's a `numpy` function. `.values` converts `series` to a numpy array and then we can use `.argmin`.

Comment: @FilipSzczybura Looks like `.argmin` and `.idxmin` work same way for the sereis, both of them give index for minimum value. `.argmin` on series is also deprecated for pandas >0.21.0